# Cannot find Add Reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I want to add some references but cannot seem to find the add reference option. I have googled and people have said its in the project menu, but for me, the project menu only shows the export template option and nothing else. Any fix for this?

Comment: To make sure we're talking about the same menu, could you edit your question to include a screenshot of your Project menu?

Comment: Can you confirm that you currently have open a C# project, and not another project type?

Comment: Yes, it is a C# project. Here is the project menu im talking about, https://imgur.com/3z70jM6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't look in the menu bar at the top of Visual Studio, instead in the Solution Explorer window, right-click on the project and look inside the popup menu.  Even better, right-click on the References node inside the project.

[image]

If you have closed or having trouble finding the Solution Explorer window, it can be found from the top-level "View" menu.

[image]

The reference-manipulation options *are* also available in the top menu bar, but that menu bar is highly context-sensitive and items will appear and disappear depending on which MDI child window has focus.  Best to use Solution Explorer.

You will need to have "Folder View" turned off.  Solution Explorer in Folder View mode is not displaying your solution at all, but your project directory, and in my estimation it's pretty obvious that such a different view should have gone in a different window with a different name.  The "Solutions and Folders" icon in the Solution Explorer toolbar will toggle between "Solution Explorer" and "Solution Explorer - Folder View"

[image]

As it turns out, "Folder View" is also what has removed all of the project-related items from the menu bar "Project" menu.  **When in folder view you are using Visual Studio as a fancy code editor with no project support.**  Even the File menu "Open Project/Solution" and "Close Solution" items disappear, replaced by "Open Folder" and "Close Folder".  The Build menu options for working with projects and solutions all disappear, replaced by "Build Document".

I do not understand why a toggle that changes the mode of the entire development environment is hidden away inside the "Solution Explorer" tool window, and phrased in a manner that suggests it just changes the presentation of one treeview, but that's what it is.

Comment: I have already tried that but iI cant seem to find the Reference node and I have also right clicked on the project but it does not show Add Reference. I am not sure as to why. I am a bit new to this.

Comment: @AGMaven: Can you add a screenshot of what your Solution Explorer window does look like?

Comment: This is what my Solution Explorer looks like. https://imgur.com/hB32ZuL

Comment: @AGMaven: Scroll up, it's the top few entries that matter.  Also, **turn off Folder View**

Comment: Scroll up where? If you are talking about the Solution Explorer, only the bin folder and the main folder is there. And how do I turn off folder view?

Comment: So i cant seem to switch views. It is a dropdown for me and not just a button. Do I need to do something else to switch?

Comment: @AGMaven: It is a button with a second small dropdown arrow button next to it.  Click the main button not the arrow.  Yes, this feature BREAKS EVERY UI RULE I've ever learned.

Answer (score 0):

To add references to your project, right-click References in the Solution Explorer of your project and click Add Reference... The project must be open to view the Solution Explorer.